# Using listings linerange in tcolorbox breaks formatting

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, tcblisting, tcbinputlisting

When using `listings`'s `linerange` or `firstline`/`lastline`, the `tcolorbox` shows extra top and bottom padding, and the font is different. Is there a way to fix this, or is this a bug with `tcolorbox` that should be reported/fixed?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.txt}
line 1
line 2
line 3
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listings, xparse]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{listing only, sharp corners, top=0pc, bottom=0pc, left=0pc, right=0pc}

%\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily} % Partially fixes the font difference?
\tcbset{listingsstyle/.style={listing engine=listings}}
\NewTCBListing{cmd}{ O{} }{listingsstyle, #1}
\NewTCBInputListing{\cmdinput}{ m O{} }{listing file={#1}, listingsstyle, #2}

\begin{document}

\begin{cmd}[title={Cmd environment}]sample text\end{cmd}
\cmdinput{test.txt}[title={Cmd input command (full)}]
\cmdinput{test.txt}[title={Cmd input command (partial)},listing options={linerange={2-3}}]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Add `listing style=tcblatex` as an argument in the last `\cmdinput`

Comment: `\cmdinput{test.txt}[title={Cmd input command (partial)},listing options={style=tcblatex, linerange={2-3}}]
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified a style for the listing options.

> "This removes all options for the listings package. This includes the
> tcblisting standard style tcblatex and the encoding presets. Use this
> option, if you want to set the listings options outside of tcblisting,
> e.g. globally in the preamble."

as written on page 314 of the tcolorbox manual. So if you add `style=tcblatex` it works as you would expect it.

MWE based on your code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.txt}
line 1
line 2
line 3
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listings, xparse]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{listing only, sharp corners, top=0pc, bottom=0pc, left=0pc, right=0pc}

%\lstset{basicstyle=\small\ttfamily} % Partially fixes the font difference?
\tcbset{listingsstyle/.style={listing engine=listings}}
\NewTCBListing{cmd}{ O{} }{listingsstyle, #1}
\NewTCBInputListing{\cmdinput}{ m O{} }{listing file={#1}, listingsstyle, #2}

\begin{document}

\begin{cmd}[title={Cmd environment}]sample text\end{cmd}
\cmdinput{test.txt}[title={Cmd input command (full)}]
\cmdinput{test.txt}[title={Cmd input command (partial)},listing options={style=tcblatex, linerange={2-3}}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding the style to an `\lstset` command to make it global also works.